# Emailing an attachment to MS Teams channel with python

Tags: python, flask, microsoft-teams

When a user fills out a form on a flask website, I want to post the answers to an MS Teams channel. The form contains an optional file field.

I have the Teams channel email address and I use python + a gmail account to send a message.
When there is no file attached (file field in form left empty by the user), everything works fine.

When the user does upload a file and my python code attaches that to the email, the message never shows up in Teams, but I can see it in the sent items on the gmail account. If I then forward that very message manually, through gmail, to the same MS Teams email address, the message will go through, file attachment included.

Any idea what's going on?

Here is my python code:

```
attachment = request.files['attachment']

# Save attachment on the server
if attachment:
    new_filename = str(random.randint(0, 999 * 999)) + '_' +  attachment.filename
    attachment.save(os.path.join(app.config['ATTACHMENT_FOLDER'] , new_filename))

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = 'email@gmail.com'
msg['To'] = 'email.onmicrosoft.com@apac.teams.ms'
msg['Subject'] = f'Form submitted'
msg_text = ...

if attachment:
    with open(os.path.join(app.config['ATTACHMENT_FOLDER'], new_filename), "rb") as f:
            attachment = MIMEApplication(f.read(), Name=new_filename)
    attachment['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(new_filename)
    msg.attach(attachment)
server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com")
server.connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587)  # account managed by google
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login("email@gmail.com", "password")
server.send_message(msg, from_addr=msg['From'], to_addrs=[msg['To']])
server.quit()
```

I will add that using this code to email the file to a regular email address works fine.